# How do I get my enemy triangle to move to a specific position?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, artificial-intelligence, 2d

I'm currently using Unity and trying to start off with a basic enemy for a top down space shooter, where the enemy simply always moves forward but will rotate to go to a new position. This will be randomly generated, essentially a patrol route.

The issue that I keep having is that I can get the enemy to move, I can get them to rotate, but I cannot get them to rotate to the exact spot I want them to move towards. No matter how I try it, the enemy will rotate, but the right side of the triangle will face the position and then it will either move forward and stay on that trajectory or it will continuously rotate around the target.

```
public class EnemyController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float enemySpeed = 6f;               // The patrol speed of the enemy
    public float rotationSpeed = 5f;             // The rotation speed of the enemy

    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private Vector2 moveToTarget;

    private void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        SetRandomPatrolTarget();
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        // Determine the direction and angle to the target
        Vector2 directionToTarget = moveToTarget - rb.position;
        float angleToTarget = Mathf.Atan2(directionToTarget.y, directionToTarget.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;

        // Calculate the angle difference
        float angleDifference = Mathf.DeltaAngle(rb.rotation, angleToTarget);

        if (Mathf.Abs(angleDifference) > 0.5f)
        {
            // Rotate towards the target position
            rb.MoveRotation(rb.rotation + Mathf.Sign(angleDifference) * rotationSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
        }
        else
        {
            // Move towards the target position
            rb.velocity = transform.up * enemySpeed;
        }
    }

    private void SetRandomPatrolTarget()
    {
        // Adjust the range of the patrol target position to fit your game world
        float minX = -10f;
        float maxX = 10f;
        float minY = -5f;
        float maxY = 5f;

        moveToTarget = new Vector3(Random.Range(minX, maxX), Random.Range(minY, maxY), 0f);
    }

    private void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        // Draw attack range gizmo
        Gizmos.color = Color.red;
        Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(moveToTarget, 0.25f);
    }
}
```

This is what I currently have. I've tried a few different things. I've tried asking ChatGPT for assistance and it doesn't seem to understand what I mean when I tell it what is going wrong.

[image: The ship is currently rotating around the red debug sphere.]

Any advice as to what the issue is would be greatly helpful, i'm absolutely stumped.

Comment: Tell it to look at the spot it is going to

Comment: So the thing is, while you rotate you do not adjust the `velocity` => until you do the enemy keeps moving in the previous direction. Also if your player runs around the enemy fast enough he can trick them to never come to the `else` case and thus never follow them ;) On the other side if doing both at the same time the "rotate" around the target" issue is quite usual ... if you do not rotate fast enough you basically keep overshooting the target and fall into a continuous adjustment cycle .. can't fully be avoided but limited down if you make the rotation speed faster

Comment: You could also "break" the algorithm and add a special case so that if the enemy gets close enough and the direction is "close enough" to the target direction than allow the enemy to directly snap the direction so the go around issue doesn't occur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `Mathf.Atan2(directionToTarget.y, directionToTarget.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;` seems to be the source.
The rest of your code works on the angle being from upwards `(0, 1)`, where this is giving it to you relative to right `(1, 0)`. So it's always 90 degrees off.

To fix it, you could just subtract 90 from the above expression.
`Mathf.Atan2(directionToTarget.y, directionToTarget.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg - 90`

I would recommend this instead though. It's easier to read. `Vector2.SignedAngle(Vector2.up, directionToTarget)`. It gives the same result.

Comment: This has worked fantastically for moving the enemy in the right direction, thank you! I was hoping to have the enemy to be able to slowly rotate towards the player or target position, at the moment, this turns them directly facing their target. How would I go about fixing that?

Comment: @user3015091 I'm not sure what you mean.
I'm testing it locally and the enemy does slowly rotate towards the chosen target then launch at it.
If you're wanting it to move forward and turn at the same time, you just need to remove the if/else statements.